# Downloading a file from server to Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have some xmls which I want to put on server and in my windows phone, I will be downloading the these files and then program will do its calculations.But I don't want to put the files on server, instead of that I want to use Dropbox/Skydrive or any other to download these files. Is it good to go, or it will have too many overheads?

Or please suggest where I should store the files so later I can download the files to use under my windows phone application.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox officially haven't release SDK for windows phone yet, you can still use it using SharpBox project, click [here](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com).

Skydrive is better option, specially for windows phone application as both runs on same platform and provide better features. Response time of Skydrive on windows phone should be faster than Dropbox.